# RMI performance too slow

Tags: java, performance, jms, cpu, rmi

I have been working on a  project which is about data copy from one db to another. Written in java6. And working on distributed machines. We have 9 server machines. One is the main node which i have my main control module working on which gets copy requests and distributes the job to other 8 machines.

It was started to be coded with JMS to distribute tasks to that 8 machine before.There was an Apache Active MQ server working on another computer. But i saw it was not much appropriate and the machines need to be more tightly coupled as it was causing some code overhead and it was necessary to return a response message for all the messages sent to slave machines. I decided to change the interconnection between main node and other 8 slave machines and coded that with RMI.

I coded an RMI server for slave machines and client for main node machine. Then created threads on main node to trigger distributed-tasks at slave machines.

The thing is performance decreased drastically. Normally i was able to copy about 6GB of data in about 6 mins from one specific db to another. Now it takes more than 1 and a half hour to copy 9GB of data. It used to consume lots of CPU when the task was executing on slave machines. I was  observing CPU usage ratio more than 90%. Now it never uses more than 15%.

What i need is to understand what is causing this performance decrease. What should i do ? Should i use a troubleshooting tool ?

Edit------------

Ok i create a slave module instance on my laptop only, and sent 16 tasks to work on it and profiled CPU using jvisualvm.The results are in the pic [CPU Profiler result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWpop.png).

The control methods in the package (e.g. failTaskIfAbort(), performSanityCheck(), etc) were also present when i was using JMS for machine communication. It makes me think, RMI threads are somehow low priority or something.

I also uploaded the nps file exported from jvisualvm. You can get it here: [exported profile result](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17633663/profilersnapshot.nps)

Comment: How are you copying the data using RMI? Are you passing objects across? If so it may be that its the RMI serialization that is the issue?

Comment: What does jvisualvm in the jdk tell you?

Comment: You can't send 6-9 GB in a single RMI call, so how are you doing this?  Even 6 minutes to send 6 GB is slow unless you have a 100 Mb network.  If this is the case, I would suggest using a 1 Gb or even 10 Gb network if yo moving around large amounts of data.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, you got it wrong, i am only sending task description to machines and the modules starts fetching the data using information(query, rowid range etc.)sent by main module, and prepares statements, loads data to target db using batch inserts. I didn't change anything about the logic of data copy. I only changed the communication master and slave machines. So it is only the way the logic is triggered at slave machines.

Comment: So you are saying that JMS/RMI has very little to do with the transfer (and I assume the processing) but you are also saying it made a dramatic difference to performance. ;) BTW Even if a thread is the lowest possible priority, it will still run at 100% if there is free CPU.  Priority only matters if there is no free CPU and it has to compete with higher priority threads.

Comment: @ Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen I posted jvisualvm results. 
@pauli i am not sure if it is serialization. I trigger the execution at slave machines and somehow it takes too much time to execute. I didnt change copy logic. I only changed the messaging in between the mdules

Comment: @PeterLawrey : Yea exactly, it shouldn't have affected the performance of data copy. I just don't get why performance decreased like that. I am not sure if something little i changed caused this. I am not even sure if it is about rmi calls or not.I might have changed something else when i was coding RMI messaging interfaces between the machines. Quite confused here.

Comment: I suspect its something unrelated.  It appears your bottle neck is how long it takes to get its data from your database.  If you are downloading to 8 clients at once, you might only be getting 1/8th of the database's bandwidth per client. I would see how it performs when you have only one client (i.e. is the CPU utilisation much higher)

Comment: I agree with Peter Lawrey here. If you haven't modified the copying logic it might very well be that you have problems with the DB not coping with all the parallel transfers.

Comment: @Marc
 I do the exact same copy with another tool, it opens 16 connections to source db and 16 connections to target db. I can observe all the operations. It does that on parallel. And copies the data in about 6 mins.

I am gonna control all the changes i have made on the module to see if i can find anything that could have caused the problem.

Comment: I agree with Peter Lawrey here too. As you are shifting the gigabytes by means other than RMI, a slowdown of this order cannot possibly be attributable to RMI. Compared to the gigabytes, the RMI overhead here is vanishingly small.

Comment: @EJP checking again and again, doing all the tests i have done when i was using JMS, increasing batch insert size and jdbc rowfetchsize (which was exactly the same as JMS one before), but still too slow. I will install JMS version again to see what will happen

Comment: @PeterLawrey  Now i agree with you either.Did some CPU sampling on the module and it seems it spends about 90% at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive().So yea it is about getting the data from db.That explains why CPU usage is decreased.It awaits the db to return data.Actually i was being silly not looking in to query performance at db side.I thought i copied this 9 gb of data before and got good results.
The problem is about accessing partitioned tables,dunno why i never looked db for time consuming tasks.I trusted to the base code :) Sorry for the headache coming from a newbie :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey i am new on this site. It seems like i need to accept an answer to mark this post as solved, or do i ?
Can u post ur last comment as an answer ? so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments,

I suspect its something unrelated. It appears your bottle neck is how long it takes to get its data from your database. If you are downloading to 8 clients at once, you might only be getting 1/8th of the database's bandwidth per client. I would see how it performs when you have only one client (i.e. is the CPU utilisation much higher)

BTW: You may find the data is limited by the network adapter of your server, or the speed it can retrieve data from the database.  If its the former, you may have a spare network adapter on your server you can use to increase your bandwidth.

Comment: Well i got the server admin to check if there is any kind of resource management thingy running that limits the CPU usage, also got network team to check if there is a limit of any kind (some firewall configurations, network bandwidth limits , etc.), and asked to db admins :D no limit, and i copy same amount of some other table's data really really fast, so i don't really think it is  network limit or database speed limit

Comment: Did you copy it to eight different machines at once?  If you have only one query it should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Did some CPU sampling on the module and it seems it spends about 90% at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive().So yea it is about getting the data from db.That explains why CPU usage is decreased.It awaits the db to return data.Actually i was being silly not looking in to query performance at db side.I thought i copied this 9 gb of data before and got good results. The problem is about accessing partitioned tables.It has nothing to do with RMI/JMS usage for task distribution.